# Importing oe_main.sql returns "no privileges on tablespace USERS"

Tags: database, oracle, sqlplus, oracle12c

After importing `hr_main.sql` into my oracle database, the next step is to import `oe_main.sql` however I am getting the issue where no rows are inserted into tables because ***"no privileges on tablespace 'USERS'"***

I checked the `oe_main.sql` script file and there is this caluse : 
`ALTER USER oe DEFAULT TABLESPACE &tbs QUOTA UNLIMITED ON &tbs;`
So I think it should work when I use `users` as the table space but it doesn't

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the issue is solved, I had to use a different tablespace
I created it using

`CREATE TABLESPACE tbs_03 
   DATAFILE 'tbs_f03.dbf' SIZE 20M
   LOGGING;`